# Get n closest neighbors to each point in a dataset using KNN in Weka

Tags: for-loop, classification, weka, knn, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataset let's say with 1000 records (points). I want, for each point in the data, to get N closest neighbors to that point and build a model using those neighbors (excluding the point). I would need a for loop to do this, and I have to perform this in Weka. How can I get N closest neighbors to each point in Weka?

Comment: Presumably, you are writing code, not using the GUI. What language is your code in? Java?

Comment: @G5W Appreciate your answer. Since I needed an immediate solution,  I wrote the code in python to perform this... without Weka. Just pure python.

Answer (score 0):

For finding the k-nearest neighbours, use the weka class:

> NearestNeighbourSearch

which has a method called

> kNearestNeighbours(Instance target, int k)

where **target** is your instance to which you want to find the N-nearest neighbours, and **k** here is N. This method's return type is Instances, hence you will get your N number of nearest neighbours.

[read more about this class here](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/)

Comment: Thank you. I need to do this for more than 100,000 instances. So I need a mechanism that enables me to iterate through them. Any idea how this can be done in Weka?

Comment: Yea. Just iterate through all the instances in a loop, for each instance use that kNearestNeighbour(...) method. Then use the instances returned by that method to build your model

Comment: That was actually the question... how can I do that? How can I write a for loop in Weka?

Comment: @G5W is the above question for me?

Comment: Sorry,  No.  I meant it for geek2000.  I will move the comment.

Comment: @Jerry if any of you guys still use this, can you tell me a little bit more of this? or where can I look for a complete example of practical use, like movies or food or something like that because I don't really get what an instance is, spare some documentation that I can read from scratch please?

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast Do you mean an example of kNN being used practically?

Comment: @Jerry yes plase mate, with weka in java if possible I have my own question here if you wanna help me with it :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739084/where-can-i-find-practical-example-of-knn-in-java-using-weka