# Where can I find practical example of KNN in java using weka

Tags: weka, knn

I have been searching for a practical example of KNN implementation using weka, but all I find is too general for me to understand the data that it needs to be able to work (or maybe how to make the objects that it needs to work) and also the results it shows, maybe someone that has worked with it before has a better example like with realistic things (products, movies, books, etc) and not the typical letters you see on algebra.

So I can figure out how to implement it on my case (which is recommend dishes to active user with KNN), would be highly appreciated, thanks.

I was trying to understand with this link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-weka3/index.html but I don't even understand how did they get this results and how did they get the formula

[image: knn]

Step 1:  Determine Distance Formula

```
Distance = SQRT( ((58 - Age)/(69-35))^2) + ((51000 - Income)/(150000-38000))^2 )
```

why is it always /(69-35) and also /(150000-38000) ?

EDIT:

Heres the Code I have tried without success, if someone can clear it for me I appreacite, also I did this code by combining this 2 answers:

This answer shows how to get the knn:

[How to get the nearest neighbor in weka using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554796/how-to-get-the-nearest-neighbor-in-weka-using-java)

And this one tells me how to create instances (which I don't really know what they are for weka) [Adding a new Instance in weka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118132/adding-a-new-instance-in-weka)

So I came up with this:

```
public class Wekatest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Attribute> atts = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> classVal = new ArrayList<>();
        // I don't really understand whats happening here
        classVal.add("A");
        classVal.add("B");
        classVal.add("C");
        classVal.add("D");
        classVal.add("E");
        classVal.add("F");

        atts.add(new Attribute("content", (ArrayList<String>) null));
        atts.add(new Attribute("@@class@@", classVal));

        // Here in my case the data to evaluate are dishes (plato mean dish in spanish)
        Instances dataRaw = new Instances("TestInstancesPlatos", atts, 0);

        // I imagine that every instance is like an Object that will be compared with the other instances, to get its neaerest neightbours (so an instance is like a dish for me)..

        double[] instanceValue1 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue1[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Pizzas");
        instanceValue1[1] = 0;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue1));

        double[] instanceValue2 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue2[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Tunas");
        instanceValue2[1] = 1;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue2));

        double[] instanceValue3 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue3[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Pizzas");
        instanceValue3[1] = 2;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue3));

        double[] instanceValue4 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue4[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Hamburguers");
        instanceValue4[1] = 3;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue4));

        double[] instanceValue5 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue5[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Pizzas");
        instanceValue5[1] = 4;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue5));

        System.out.println("---------------------");

        weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch knn = new LinearNNSearch(dataRaw);
        try {

            // This method receives the goal instance which you wanna know its neighbours and N (I don't really know what N is but I imagine it is the number of neighbours I want)
            Instances nearestInstances = knn.kNearestNeighbours(dataRaw.get(0), 1);
            // I expected the output to be the closes neighbour to dataRaw.get(0) which would be Pizzas, but instead I got some data that I don't really understand.


            System.out.println(nearestInstances);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

OUTPUT:

---------------------
@relation TestInstancesPlatos

@attribute content string
@attribute @@class@@ {A,B,C,D,E,F}

@data
Pizzas,A
Tunas,B
Pizzas,C
Hamburguers,D
```

weka dependency used:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
        <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: 69 is the highest age, 35 the smallest, the subtraction gets you the range, this normalizes the difference of 58 (the observation we want to find the distance to) to every other observation but scaled to fall between 0 (equality) and 1 (maximum possible difference). This is done with income as well as age an income are on massively different scales.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach thank you for the acclaration man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KNN is a machine learning technique usually classified as an "Instance-Based predictor". It takes all **instances** of classified samples and draws them in a n-dimensional space.

Using algorithms such as Euclidean distance, KNN looks for the closest points in this n-dimensional space and estimates to which class it belongs based on these neighbors. If it is closer to blue dots, it is blue, if its closer to red dots...

But now, how could we apply it to your problem?

Imagine that you only have two attributes, price and calories (2 dimensional space). You want to classify customers into three classes: fit, junk-food, gourmet. With this, you can offer a deal in a restaurant similar to the customer's preferences.

You have the following data:

```
+-------+----------+-----------+
| Price | Calories | Food Type |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| $2    |    350   | Junk Food |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| $5    |    700   | Junk Food |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| $10   |    200   | Fit       |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| $3    |    400   | Junk Food |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| $8    |    150   | Fit       |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| $7    |    650   | Junk Food |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| $5    |    120   | Fit       |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| $25   |    230   | Gourmet   |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| $12   |    210   | Fit       |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| $40   |    475   | Gourmet   |
+-------+----------+-----------+
| $37   |    600   | Gourmet   |
+-------+----------+-----------+
```

Now, let's see it plotted in a 2D space:

[image: Plot]

What happens next?

For every new entry, the algorithm calculates the distance to all dots (instances) and find the k nearest ones. From the class of these k nearest ones, it defines the class of the new entry.

Take k = 3 and values $15 and 165 cal. Let's find the 3 nearest neighbors:

[image: New classif]

There's where the Distance formula comes on. It actually makes this computation for every dot. These distances are then "ranked" and the k closest ones compose the final class.

Now, Why the values /(69-35) and also /(150000-38000)? As mentioned in other answers, this is due to normalization. Our example uses price and cal. As seen, calories are in a greater order than money (more units per value). To avoid inbalances, such as the one that can make calories more valuable for class than price (which would kill Gourmet class, for example), there's the need to make all attributes similarly important, hence the use of normalization.

Weka abstracts that for you, but you can visualize it as well. See an example of visualization from a project I made for a Weka ML course:

[image: WekaVisualize]

Notice that, since there are many more than 2 dimensions, there are a lot of plots, but the idea is similar.

Explaining the code:

```
public class Wekatest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//These two ArrayLists are the inputs of your algorithm.
//atts are the attributes that you're going to pass for training, usually called X.
//classVal is the target class that is to be predicted, usually called y.
        ArrayList<Attribute> atts = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> classVal = new ArrayList<>();
//Here you initiate a "dictionary" of all distinct types of restaurants that can be targeted.
        classVal.add("A");
        classVal.add("B");
        classVal.add("C");
        classVal.add("D");
        classVal.add("E");
        classVal.add("F");
// The next two lines initiate the attributes, one made of "content" and other pertaining to the class of the already labeled values.
        atts.add(new Attribute("content", (ArrayList<String>) null));
        atts.add(new Attribute("@@class@@", classVal));

//This loads a Weka object of data for training, using attributes and classes from a file "TestInstancePlatos" (or should happen).
//dataRaw contains a set of previously labelled instances that are going to be used do "train the model" (kNN actually doesn't tain anything, but uses all data for predictions)
        Instances dataRaw = new Instances("TestInstancesPlatos", atts, 0);


//Here you're starting new instances to test your model. This is where you can substitute for new inputs for production.
        double[] instanceValue1 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

//It looks you only have 2 attributes, a food product and a rating maybe.
        instanceValue1[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Pizzas");
        instanceValue1[1] = 0;

//You're appending this new instance to the model for evaluation.
        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue1));

        double[] instanceValue2 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue2[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Tunas");
        instanceValue2[1] = 1;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue2));

        double[] instanceValue3 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue3[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Pizzas");
        instanceValue3[1] = 2;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue3));

        double[] instanceValue4 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue4[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Hamburguers");
        instanceValue4[1] = 3;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue4));

        double[] instanceValue5 = new double[dataRaw.numAttributes()];

        instanceValue5[0] = dataRaw.attribute(0).addStringValue("Pizzas");
        instanceValue5[1] = 4;

        dataRaw.add(new DenseInstance(1.0, instanceValue5));

// After adding 5 instances, time to test:
        System.out.println("---------------------");

//Load the algorithm with data.
        weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch knn = new LinearNNSearch(dataRaw);
//You're predicting the class of value 0 of your data raw values. You're asking the answer among 1 neighbor (second attribute)
        try {
            Instances nearestInstances = knn.kNearestNeighbours(dataRaw.get(0), 1);
//You will get a value among A and F, that are the classes passed.
           System.out.println(nearestInstances);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

How should you do it?

```
-> Gather data. 
-> Define a set of attributes that help you to predict which cousine you have (ex.: prices, dishes or ingredients (have one attribute for each dish or ingredient). 
-> Organize this data. 
-> Define a set of labels.
-> Manually label a set of data.
-> Load labelled data to KNN.
-> Label new instances by passing their attributes to KNN. It'll return you the label of the k nearest neighbors (good values for k are 3 or 5, have to test).
-> Have fun!
```

Comment: Hey man thank you very much for your explanation, its alot clearer for me now, atleast the way the algorithm works, if you could also add some little code to your answer and explain it, it would be gold valueable answer, I added the code I tried to my question, but I don't really understand how it works, if you clear that out I appreciate, you are the winner of my bounty so far :)

Comment: I can't review the link you provided me at the moment, but I will as soon as I can

Comment: This "Pizzas", "Tunas", etc, are like the products sold in a restaurant?

Comment: Yes mate, they are

Comment: And the number? a rating?

Comment: The thing is I have an active user, the system will show him dishes that he might like, based on what other users have searched similar dishes, so for example if "user A" searchs Pizzas, system should look for other users that have searched pizzas too, and after that I show recomendation of dishes that this other users have searched to user A. The number you are asking me I don't understand what it is, I got exactly that code from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118132/adding-a-new-instance-in-weka

Comment: The guy who answered didn't exaplain alot the code, but it makes sense that it is a rating, so for my case it would be number of times it has been searched by an user, I wanted to get the user that has the most Pizza searchs, that would be closest neighbour, so I show what this user has searched to "user A"

Comment: So you had some mistake. Probably what you need is a Clustering algorithm, rather than KNN. It is similar, but not the same thing.

Comment: For clustering, check K-means algorithm. If you want to use KNN you have to define a set of "customer groups" before.

Comment: I will check that algorithm to bro, I just saw your code is much clear now, do you think I can use KNN if instead of using "number of searchs by user" I use the name of the dish and also the type of food? like product name pizza, type of food junk food, so that way I think I can use it or do I need a numerical value? I could use prices

Comment: Or how do you think I could define this customer groups, I could check on my data the searchs that has been made by users and classify them in "users tha search for junk food" "users that search for healthy food" stuff like that?

Comment: Yes, you could do it. Regarding categorical variables, what you should have is a "column" for each category and have a boolean value for exists or not. If you hae a lot of unlabelled data, you can use clustering to find clusters (which are going to be your customer groups), set them to be the classes and then use KNN to make suggestions for new users. Check clustering, its simple and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks alot friend :)

Comment: Hey Tiago just wanted to let you know that the algorithm its working now and I was able to implement it on my project, im not 100% sure if the data is correct but the thing is its working lol, thanks alot friend, wanted to ask you small favour if you can upvote this question? thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Its Fairly Simple.
In order to understand why is it always /(69-35) and also /(150000-38000), You first need to understand what Normalization means.

**Normalization**:
Normalization usually means to scale a variable to have a values between 0 and 1.
The formula is as follows:

[image]

If you closely look at the denominator of the above formula, you will observe that it's the max value of all the number subtracted from the min value of all the number.

Now, Get back to you question... Look at the 5th line of the Question. Its says as follow.

> The easiest and most common distance calculation is the "Normalized
>   Euclidian Distance."

In you Age column, you can see that the min value is 35 and the max value is 69.Similarly, in your Income column you min value is 38k and max would be 150k.

This is the exact reason that you always have it /(69-35) and also /(150000-38000).

Hope you have understood it.

PEACE

Comment: I understand it much better now, if you can add code example too I appreciate

Comment: Hey @BugsForBreakfast, I have no idea about using weka... But I can explain you with python code... is that OK with you..?

Comment: Yes I know Python too maybe I can understand how it works in python and implement in java, everything helps mate